# Why does <button> still have padding in Firefox when set to 0

Tags: html, css, firefox

Can someone please explain why the `<button>` element still has a bit of padding regardless of the styling? Compare the four elements in the snippet below: `<button> <a> <span> <div>` which all have identical style applied.  The last three look identical but the button stubbornly refuses to lose the padding in Firefox.  Inspector shows that it renders identical in Chrome but not Firefox.

Is there a CSS rule I can apply to control this?

```css
.style {
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button class="style">TEST</button>
<a class="style">TEST</a>
<span class="style">TEST</span>
<div class="style">TEST</div>
```

Comment: You can inspect in firebug, there is no padding of button it is just user agent margin to body tag.

Comment: Correct, there is no padding.. but yet.. there is.  And the button is a different pixel size.  What user agent style is doing this?

Comment: Yes, different useragent have their own css, also your settings of your browsers like font-size, color etc.

Comment: According to the linked question, the solution is `button::-moz-focus-inner { padding: 0; border: 0; }`. It seems that normalize.css will do this for you.

Comment: @torazaburo - thanks... searched but failed to find that one.

Comment: It seems that this bug is going to be fixed in FF 53.0a1, see https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/f86ce2e2f6a5. Also, note that this fix might need to be applied to `input` elements as well. Finally, be aware that the patch using `-moz-focus-inner` will remove focusing behavior.

Comment: that may be but I'm stuck on v49 at the moment due to issues with Firebug on v50+ - namely script panel was (is?) broken.

Answer (score -1):

It is basically firefox browser's issue so try to add `button::-moz-focus-inner {padding: 0;border: 0}`

```css
.style {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0
}
```

```html
<button class="style">TEST</button>
<a class="style">TEST</a>
<span class="style">TEST</span>
<div class="style">TEST</div>
```

Comment: Nope.. button is still larger.

Comment: It's possible that this differs with OS or Firefox version but in my browser they are not the same size.

Comment: No all are of ```36px X 16px```

Comment: Which browser you are testing?

Comment: @aavrug problem is in firefox

Comment: proof: http://zuma-design.com/shared/so/buttons.png

Comment: This is really seems fixed.